# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input - Javascript error

Tags: javascript

I get this error when i try to call this function in Chrome 16.0.912.77 m:

```
function fade(e){
    if(op > 0){
        op -= 0.01;
        document.getElementById(e).style.opacity = op;
        window.setTimeout("fade(\""+e+")\"", 10);
    }
}
```

It's a simple function which fade a element on my page out.
I read that the error appears when i forgett a }-bracket, but i closed all..

Any ideas?

Comment: could you add the rendered html too?

Comment: and if you do `setTimeout(function() { fade(e) },10);`instead?

Comment: As an aside, you should avoid passing a string to `setTimeout` since it is a form of `eval`.  See [`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout#Syntax) at MDN for more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
window.setTimeout("fade(\""+e+"\")", 10);
```

You have the closing quote and closing parentheses swapped.

Comment: Better code: 
`setTimeout(() => fade(\`"${e}"\`), 10);`

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect this in your favourite JavaScript console:

```
var e = "foo";
alert("fade(\""+e+")\"");
```

... you'll see this:

```
fade("foo)"
```

Use on your favour the fact that JavaScript allows both single and double quotes:

```
var e = "foo";
alert('fade("' + e+ '")');
```

Or, even better, call [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) with a function reference instead of a string (find some examples in the linked page).